# How do I unit test Spring Batch partition worker steps?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-batch

I'm familiar with unit testing Spring Batch job steps (and entire jobs), but am wondering if there is a way to unit test a "worker" step for a partition (without testing the whole partition step).

The thing I'm puzzling over is that typically a unit test for a step would call:

`JobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(stepName, jobParameters, jobExecutionContext)`

But, this being a worker step within a partition, I need some way of also passing in a StepExecutionContext. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What is the type of your worker step? Is it a simple tasklet or a chunk oriented tasklet?

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine - it's chunked.

Comment: ok thanks, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you don't trust `Step` implementations provided by Spring Batch, I would test the component (which needs to read values from the step execution context) used within the worker step and not the worker step itself. Let me give two examples:

#### Chunk-oriented worker step

In this case, I would unit test the component (reader, processor or writer) that needs to access a value from the step execution context and not the chunk-oriented step itself (which is provided by Spring Batch and should be trusted, unless you don't trust it).

#### Simple tasklet worker step

If the worker step is a simple tasklet, you can unit test the `Tasklet` itself and not the `TaskletStep`.

In both cases, the component (reader/processor/writer or tasklet) should be step scoped to get access to the step execution context and you can mock/stub the step execution context as needed. Please refer to the [Testing Step-Scoped Components](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/testing.html#testing-step-scoped-components) fro more details.